# Working with usb drivers libusb, usb4java ecc.. why it's so unsupported?

Tags: java, c++, c, usb, hid

Trying to work with an USB HID project made with a microprocessor, just want to send a packet of 64 bytes, and can't understand why it must be so difficult to do.
Serial communication is so supported, but usb not, both for java or c++ or c# or what you want.
I really can't understand this point, usb is the most used hardware interface and, for example, in java you have to install external libs to use the usb yes, cause you have different drivers in different systems, but for me is a very important point USB.
If u can point me to a simple working library just to send asynchronous packets both java, c, c++, I will be very happy.
Thanks for reading.